# MySQL PHP Query Optimization - Feedbacks

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache, optimization

I need to run this script every day(cron) to update the 1 month total amount of feedbacks(at least that's what I have devised now). Here is the code I have. Does anybody have a better idea about how I should got about this? Maybe changing around the way I go about this or optimizing my updateMonthlyFeedback.php script?

**updateMonthlyFeedback.php**

```
session_start();
include("db.php");

$sql="SELECT MAX(uid) as maxUID FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$maxUID = $row['maxUID'];

for($i=0;$i<$maxUID;$i++){
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as negativeCount FROM feedbacks WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = -1 AND uid = '$i'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $negativeCount = $row['negativeCount'];
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as neutralCount FROM feedbacks WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = 0 AND uid = '$i'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $neutralCount = $row['neutralCount'];
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as positiveCount FROM feedbacks WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = 1 AND uid = '$i'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $positiveCount = $row['positiveCount'];
    $sql = "UPDATE feedback_totals SET negativeCount = '$negativeCount', neutralCount = '$neutralCount', positiveCount = '$positiveCount' WHERE uid = '$i'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**MySQL Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE feedback_totals (
    uid                     VARCHAR(40),
    negativeCount           int,
    neutralCount            int,                
    positiveCount           int,
    halfStarCount           int,
    oneStarCount            int,
    oneHalfStarCount        int,
    twoStarCount            int,
    twoHalfStarCount        int,
    threeStarCount          int,
    threeHalfStarCount      int,
    fourStarCount           int,
    fourHalfStarCount       int,
    fiveStarCount           int,
    PRIMARY KEY             (uid)
    #FOREIGN KEY            (uid) REFERENCES users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE feedback_last_month (
    uid                     VARCHAR(40),
    negativeCount           int,
    neutralCount            int,                
    positiveCount           int,
    halfStarCount           int,
    oneStarCount            int,
    oneHalfStarCount        int,
    twoStarCount            int,
    twoHalfStarCount        int,
    threeStarCount          int,
    threeHalfStarCount      int,
    fourStarCount           int,
    fourHalfStarCount       int,
    fiveStarCount           int,
    PRIMARY KEY             (uid)
    #FOREIGN KEY            (uid) REFERENCES users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE feedback (
    feedback_id             INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid                     VARCHAR(40),INDEX (uid),
    sender_id               VARCHAR(40),
    type                    int,                #-1 = neg, 0 = neutral, 1 = positive
    starCount               VARCHAR(40),
    description             VARCHAR(80),
    date_created            timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    fromType                VARCHAR(40), # buyer or seller
    fromUsername            VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY             (feedback_id)
    #FOREIGN KEY            (uid) REFERENCES users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Well the obvious first answer will be to remove the `for` loop and instead of limiting the query by the uid, `group on` the uid.

Comment: Are you sure you want to select COUNT() from *users* instead of counting the number of *feedback* rows?

Comment: Yeah I updated this. Just wrote a quick prototype and didn't test yet. Just wanted to have something rather than nothing to explain my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as everyone else said, use PDO/MYSQLI. However, using the code you already have, here are two methods that might work and perform better.

First is using correlated sub-queries to get the negative/positive/neutral values. This is nice because it is short, however it is in no way ideal. You are still performing a ton of queries on the database (3 for each uid + the initial update). However, you are only sending one query to the server from php and letting the database do all the rest of the work. This might perform fine for a few users, but after a while it will start having performance issues. This one query will update all the rows in feedback_totals. However if there isn't a row in feedback_totals, it doesn't insert a new row for any new uids.

```
//one query, this is it. updates it all.
$sql = "UPDATE `feedback_totals`
        SET
            `negativeCount`=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=`feedback_totals`.`uid` AND `date_created` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND `type`=-1),
            `positiveCount`=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=`feedback_totals`.`uid` AND `date_created` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND `type`=1),
            `neutralCount`=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=`feedback_totals`.`uid` AND `date_created` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND `type`=0)";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

Second is probably better in the long run. Query out all the data needed in one query. loop through that result formatting it in php, looping over that and doing the updates. This one will probably perform better because you are running a much lower number of queries (1 for getting the data + 1 for each uid).

```
//query for all the data
$sql="SELECT
            `uid`,
            `type`,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `date_created` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        GROUP BY `uid`,`type`";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
//loop through the result
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //if the uid is not in $data
    if(!isset($data[$row['uid']])){
        //add it with a blank array
        $data[$row['uid']] = array('negativeCount'=>0,'neutralCount'=>0,'positiveCount'=>0);
    }
    //add to the data for this uid depending on type
    if($row['type']==-1){
        $data[$row['uid']]['negativeCount']=$row['cnt'];
    } elseif($row['type']==1){
        $data[$row['uid']]['positiveCount']=$row['cnt'];
    } else {
        $data[$row['uid']]['neutralCount']=$row['cnt'];
    }
}

//now loop through the data and update the table
foreach($data as $uid=>$cnt){
    $sql = "UPDATE `feedback_totals`
            SET
                `negativeCount`={$cnt['negativeCount']},
                `positiveCount`={$cnt['positiveCount']},
                `neutralCount`={$cnt['neutralCount']}
            WHERE `uid`=$uid";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand. But from outside the code I already have. Would there be a better way of going about this? FYI The feedback totals are initialized when the user is created.

Comment: The code I gave is just a reconfigure of your code. It should work as a direct replacement. Both *should* work (I don't have your database to test against) and still perform better than the code you have.

Comment: Like should I be updating these totals everyday or is there a better way?

Comment: well generally if you can calculate the totals from the data in the database, you don't need to store the totals elsewhere. It is just duplication then. And looking up the count(*) for the last 30 days for any number of users really isn't going to be that hard for a database to query on the fly when it is needed.

Comment: I just thought preprocessing these 1 month totals would be better than constantly doing counts on the database. I might just use that as it would in real time than by day.

Comment: well how many counts do you think you will query on a page? I don't know what this is for, but I can't imagine much on a single page load. And if you are showing the count for a lot of users, use the query I posted in the second answer to get the numbers for all the users on the page (add to the where clause `AND uid IN (1,2,3)` to get the count for a list of users), store it in the array like I do and then as you loop over the users to display you can lookup the value for any specific user by uid.

Comment: It's just a feedback overview for 1 user per page load.

Comment: Then just do it in real time. It would seriously be 1-2 milliseconds you are saving by pre-caching. Use the query I provided in the second answer to just do one query to get all 3 counts and modify the where to include `uid=$uid`

Comment: Well that solves it. PDO plus no monthly totals table. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's obviously quite a lot of repetition going on here. Most of it could be removed by refactoring the code, but as a starting point even with the current process, you could make it perform better by using a better database API.

So the first thing I'd recommend is to stop using the `mysql_xxx()` functions, and switch to using the `PDO` library instead. The old `mysql` functions are deprecated anyway, so it's not recommended to use them if at all possible, but in this case there's a specific reason for using `PDO` instead because it has significant performance benefits over the old functions.

PDO allows you to use a feature called Prepared Queries allows the database to cache queries more efficiently if you to call similar queries repeatedly.

Secondly, the queries themselves. Yes, these could definitely be simplified. The three queries in the loop could be combined into a single query using `GROUP BY`. The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY )
AND uid = :uid
AND type = -1 OR type = 1 OR type = 1
GROUP BY type
```

You should get the same three values from this query as three records to fetch.

There's quite a bit more you could do, but that's a good start. I'm sure you'll get other answers to help you further.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run three queries to get the info you need:

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(*) as negativeCount FROM users
WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = -1 
GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid ASC";

SELECT uid, COUNT(*) as neutralCount FROM users
WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = 0
GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid ASC";

SELECT uid, COUNT(*) as positiveCount FROM users
WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = 1 
GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid ASC";
```

And then I would walk the results, incrementing the rows as they lined up with the current uid.  The one tricky bit with the returned results is that the absence of a uid indicates a count of 0. But they are ordered, so you would know to increment the returned result (either via the fetch_row you are using) or an individual index for each of the results.

It would look something like this:

```
// Have to load up the first result
$p_row = mysql_fetch_array($positive_result);
$neu_row = mysql_fetch_array($neutral_result);
$neg_row = mysql_fetch_array($negative_result);

for($i = 0; $i < $maxUID; $i++){
  $positive = $neutral = $negative = 0;
  if($p_row[0] == $i){
    $positive = $p_row[1];
    $p_row = mysql_fetch_array($positive_result);
  }
  if($neu_row[0] == $i){
    $neutral = $neu_row[1];
    $neu_row = mysql_fetch_array($neutral_result);
  }
  if($neg_row[0] == $i){
    $negative = $neg_row[1];
    $neg_row = mysql_fetch_array($negative_result);
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE feedback_totals SET negativeCount = '$negative', neutralCount = '$neutral', positiveCount = '$positive' WHERE uid = '$i'";
  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of this can be accomplished with a single SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `feedback_totals` (uid,negativeCount,positiveCount,neutralcount)
SELECT users.uid, 
  COUNT(neg.feedback_id) as negativeCount, 
  COUNT(pos.feedback_id) as positiveCount, 
  COUNT(neut.feedback_id) AS neutralCount
FROM users
LEFT JOIN feedback neg  ON neg.uid =users.uid AND neg.type=-1 AND neg.date_created >=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
LEFT JOIN feedback pos  ON pos.uid =users.uid AND pos.type=1  AND pos.date_created >=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
LEFT JOIN feedback neut ON neut.uid=users.uid AND neut.type=0 AND neut.date_created>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY uid
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  negativeCount=VALUES(negativeCount), 
  positiveCount=VALUES(positiveCount), 
  neutralCount=VALUES(neutralCount);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will allow the query to add new rows as well as update existing ones. You can play with this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f15f4/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

first try change your Mysql for mysqli

just change your db.php for:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

And change your code for:

```
session_start();
include("db.php");
$sql="SELECT MAX(uid) as maxUID FROM users; ";

for($i=0;$i<$maxUID;$i++){
    $sql.="SELECT COUNT(*) as negativeCount FROM users WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = -1 AND uid = '$i'; ";
    $sql.="SELECT COUNT(*) as neutralCount FROM users WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = 0 AND uid = '$i'; ";
    $sql.="SELECT COUNT(*) as positiveCount FROM users WHERE date_created >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) AND type = 1 AND uid = '$i'; ";
    $sql.="UPDATE feedback_totals SET negativeCount = '$negativeCount', neutralCount = '$neutralCount', positiveCount = '$positiveCount' WHERE uid = '$i'; ";
}   

if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        $rows=array();
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
            array_pop($rows); 
            $result->free();
        }
        $data[]=$rows;
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
    print_r($data);
} else
    echo "Error with SQL";
```

That will onlye make one batch connection to the DB, and will print all the data in an array.

Comment: if you're going to change DB API anyway, you may as well go with PDO; it's better than mysqli.